# DateFormat Android - properly?

Tags: java, android, date, string-formatting

I am wondering how to properly display dates in Android. I mean date-formats, which fit to the specific region, where the application is downloaded.
What I am doing atm is:

```
DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
String[] dateParts = date.split(DATE_DELIMITER);
Date temp = new Date(Integer.valueOf(dateParts[4])-1900, Integer.valueOf(dateParts[3]),
            Integer.valueOf(dateParts[2]), Integer.valueOf(dateParts[0]),
            Integer.valueOf(dateParts[1]));
return formatter.format(temp);
```

So... There are following problems with this: Java.util.Date is marked as deprecated, and it displays me seconds too, although I don't want that.

Is there any "Beautiful" solution for that? I'd be glad if you could tell me :)

Comment: to all answers yet: What I don't want is a fixxed position of "date and month" as different regions handle this differently. E.g. europe is used to DD.MM. UK or US is sometimes used to MM/DD and so on. Is there no way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

To format a date for the current Locale, use one of the static factory methods:

```
String formattedString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(yourDate);
```

This will format accordingly to the device current locale, that is the one configured in android settings.

[More Info](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)

---

A solution is to use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
public static vod FormatDate(Date yourDate) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    return sdf.format( yourDate ));

}
```

Related: [Android SimpleDateFormat, how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277747/android-simpledateformat-how-to-use-it)

Answer (score 2):

**Android DateFormat Using Device Current Locale**

In android you can use the device's locale while formatting your date object by doing this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
String formatedText = sdf.format(new Date());
```

**Edit**

To use the exact system Date Formates use:

```
        DateFormat.getDateFormat(mContext).format(new Date());
```

Comment: won't this still display the date in yyyy-mm-dd ?