# how to convert yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+05:30 to hh:mm:ss AM/PM in android

Tags: android, datetime

I am receiving date and time format  as mentioned below

2016-04-13T00:12:33+05:30

i need to convert above format to HH:MM:SS AM/PM

can any one guide me,your response will be appreciated......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SimpleDateFormat, how to use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277747/android-simpledateformat-how-to-use-it)

Comment: only follow the rules of API: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
Log.i("date ====== " + formatter.format("2016-04-13T00:12:33+05:30"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Android has the DateFormat class for parsing and reformatting dates as Strings, but JodaTime is much better.  JodaTime is small and can handle what you're looking for in just a couple lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You need first String to Date using Simple forma tor

Then date need to change to formatResult fro expected result

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

  SimpleDateFormat formatResult  = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
```