# change the Date format in android

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I made a Dialog named 'DatePickerFragment' so the user can pick the date from and it'll be shown in a Button;

How can I change the format?
the current format is like this: "THU AUG 24 00:00:00 GMT+04:30 2017"

I want to ignore time and just show like this: "08-04-2017"

Here is my DatePickerFragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public static final String EXTRA_DATE = "com.drgnme.listhamrah.date";

    private static final String ARG_DATE = "date";

    private DatePicker mDatePicker;

    public static DatePickerFragment newInstance (Date date) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_DATE, date);

        DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Date date = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_DATE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
                .inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);

        mDatePicker = (DatePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_picker);
        mDatePicker.init(year, month, day, null);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(v)
                .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
//                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        int year = mDatePicker.getYear();
                        int month = mDatePicker.getMonth();
                        int day = mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();

                        Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();
                        sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, date);
                    }
                })
                .create();
    }

    private void sendResult (int resultCode, Date date) {
        if (getTargetFragment() == null) {
            return;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE, date);

        getTargetFragment()
                .onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, intent);
    }

}
```

and this is the fragment contain the button sets date:

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_DETAIL_ID = "detail_id";
private static final String DIALOG_DATE = "DialogDate";
private static final String DIALOG_PHOTO = "DialogPhoto";

private static final int REQUEST_DATE = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_PHOTO = 2;

private Detail mDetail;
private File mPhotoFile;
private EditText mTitleField;
private EditText mDescriptionField;
private Button mDateButton;
private RatingBar mRatingBar;
private Button mReportButton;
private ImageButton mPhotoButton;
private ImageView mPhotoView;


public static DetailFragment newInstance (UUID detailId) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(ARG_DETAIL_ID, detailId);

    DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    UUID detailId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_DETAIL_ID);
    mDetail = DetailLab.get(getActivity()).getDetail(detailId);

    mPhotoFile = DetailLab.get(getActivity()).getPhotoFile(mDetail);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    DetailLab.get(getActivity()).updateDetail(mDetail);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater,
                          ViewGroup container,
                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail,
            container, false);

    mTitleField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.detail_title);
    mTitleField.setText(mDetail.getTitle());
    mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                                      int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                                  int start, int before, int count) {
            mDetail.setTitle(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });


    mDescriptionField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.detail_description);
    mDescriptionField.setText(mDetail.getDes());
    mDescriptionField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                                      int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                                  int start, int before, int count) {
            mDetail.setDes(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });


    mDateButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.detail_date);
    updateDate();
    mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment
                    .newInstance(mDetail.getDate());
            dialog.setTargetFragment(DetailFragment.this, REQUEST_DATE);
            dialog.show(manager, DIALOG_DATE);
        }
    });


    mRatingBar = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    mRatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar,
                                    float rating,
                                    boolean fromUser) {

        }
    });

    mReportButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.detail_report);
    mReportButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v) {


            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getDetailReport());
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    getString(R.string.detail_report_subject));
            i = Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.send_report));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();

    mPhotoButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.detail_camera);
    final Intent captureImage =
            new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    boolean canTakePhoto = mPhotoFile != null &&
            captureImage.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null;
    mPhotoButton.setEnabled(canTakePhoto);

    mPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                    "com.drgnme.listhamrah.fileprovider",
                    mPhotoFile );
            captureImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);

            List<ResolveInfo> cameraActivities = getActivity()
                    .getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(captureImage,
                            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

            for (ResolveInfo activity : cameraActivities) {
                getActivity().grantUriPermission(activity.activityInfo.packageName,
                        uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            }
            startActivityForResult(captureImage, REQUEST_PHOTO);
        }
    });

    mPhotoView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.detail_photo);
    mPhotoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            if (mPhotoFile == null || !mPhotoFile.exists()) return; //no photo
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            PhotoZoomFragment dialog = new PhotoZoomFragment()
                    .newInstance(mPhotoFile.getPath());
            dialog.show(manager, DIALOG_PHOTO);
        }
    });

    updatePhotoView();
    return v;
    }

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_detail, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete_detail:

            DetailLab.get(getActivity()).deleteDetail(mDetail);
            getActivity().finish();
            return true;


        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

    @Override
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode,
                              int resultCode,
                              Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATE) {
            Date date = (Date) data
                    .getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
            mDetail.setDate(date);
            updateDate();
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_PHOTO) {
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                    "com.drgnme.listhamrah.fileprovider",
                    mPhotoFile);

            getActivity().revokeUriPermission(uri,
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            updatePhotoView();

        }
    }

private void updateDate() {
    mDateButton.setText(mDetail.getDate().toString());
}


private String getDetailReport() {
    String dateFormat = "EEE, MMM dd";
    String dateString = DateFormat.format(
            dateFormat, mDetail.getDate()).toString();

    String rateString = null;

    String report = getString(R.string.detail_report,
            mDetail.getTitle(), dateString,
            rateString, rateString
            );

    return report;
}

private void updatePhotoView() {
    if (mPhotoFile == null || !mPhotoFile.exists()) {
        mPhotoView.setImageDrawable(null);
    } else {
        Bitmap bitmap = PictureUtils.getScaledBitmap(
                mPhotoFile.getPath(), getActivity());
        mPhotoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SimpleDateFormat, how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277747/android-simpledateformat-how-to-use-it)

Comment: `Java` is not `JavaScript`, do not use `JavaScript` snippet to show `Java` code...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto o.O i do knoW, tnx to remind

Comment: @kapsym yea i saw that page before, but i'm new in Android/Java, so i couldn't use these in my code, and i postEd all my code here :/

Comment: Show the code, that sets the button's text...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto i edited my post))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity result:

```
Date date = (Date)intent.getExtras().get(EXTRA_DATE);

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

String timeStr = format.format(date);
```

`timeStr` will contain the formatted date as you need it.

Comment: sorry but should i use it in y sendResult method? coZ i did bt it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 String date="THU AUG 24 00:00:00 GMT+04:30 2017";
SimpleDateFormat spf=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date newDate= null;
try {
    newDate = spf.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
spf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
date = spf.format(newDate);
Log.e("date",date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tho other answers' formatting in the method `updateDate()`, something like this:

```
private void updateDate() {
    mDateButton.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(mDetail.getDate()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I should just use "SimpleDateFormat("xxxxx..") in my `updateDate()` method,

it worked for me:

```
private void updateDate() {
mDateButton.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(mDetail.getDate())); }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using SimpleDateFormat to format the time.
such as：

```html
 SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
 String result = sf.format("you data");
```

Comment: Could u please check my Code && tell me the specific place for using this? Thanks in advancE