# SimpleDateFormat returns different result

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I am trying to parse a `string` to a `SimpleDateFormat`, however it doesn't display the `yyyy-MM-dd` format that I made.

This is the result:

> Sun Jun 23 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019

This is what I need:

> 2019-07-23

Here's my code:

```
 onDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            String date = year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth;
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                Date datex = format.parse(date);
                System.out.println(datex);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: what is the output you got?

Comment: Have a look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35710436/5110595).

Comment: it's on the post @sasikumar

Comment: why you need to format  String date = year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth; is already giving you date in yyyy-mm-dd format in this case of yours

Comment: Yes it does return a value, however I am following a formatted date. the ` year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth` is returning the value of `2019-7-23` and what I need is `2019-07-23`

Comment: just add 1 more line format.format(datex) -- you had parsed date but not formatted it in the format you want

Comment: I got it working now, thanks @NehaRathore

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display Java.util.Date in a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262310/display-java-util-date-in-a-specific-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will you the desired result

```
String date = year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth;
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", 

    Locale.getDefault());
            Date datex = null;
            try {
                datex = format.parse(date);
                String formattedDate=format.format(datex);
                Log.e("FormattedDate",formattedDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

More simpler way to do this by following,

```
        String date = year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth;
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            Date datex = format.parse(date);
            String outputDate = format.format(datex);
            System.out.println(outputDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

This will give you the output that you asked for, `2019-07-23` (with correct month number, 07, and with leading zero):

```
onDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month + 1, dayOfMonth);
            String dateString = date.toString();
            System.out.println(dateString);
        }
    };
```

I am using `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. We need to add one to the month because `DatePicker` confusingly counts months from 0 for January through 11 for December, while `LocalDate` numbers months the same way humans do. `LocalDate.toString()` produces the `yyyy-MM-dd` format you asked for. It conforms with ISO 8601.

### What went wrong in your code?

First because, as mentioned, `DatePicker` numbers months from 0, you got the wrong month, 6 for July, so it was printed as June in your output. Second, formatting the date into a string, parsing it into a `Date` and printing that `Date` as a string is over-complicating things. Also `Date.toString()` always produces the format you saw, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`. To produce a different string from that you would have needed to format it explicitly.

In any case both `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` are poorly designed and long outdated. And the modern date and time API is so much nicer to work with. I recommend it warmly.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working fine for me to long date convert to a simple date.

```
public String getTimeStamp(long timeinMillies) {
            String date = null;
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // modify format
            date = formatter.format(new Date(timeinMillies));
            System.out.println("Today is " + date);

            return date;
        }
```

Or use this

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date d = new Date(year, month, day);
String strDate = dateFormatter.format(d);
```

Thanks, Happy Coding...

Comment: yes you are putting String date = year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth; wrong formation in method just put long date value

Comment: Sun Jun 23 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019 this is long value and you are putting string value that's why you are getting FATAL EXCEPTION

Comment: No, even if you insist on using the poorly designed and long outdated classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, you still should *not* use the deprecated `Date(int, int, int)` constructor (it’s been deprecated for decades now).

Answer (score 0):

Add this function in extension it will work

```
   fun Context.getFormattedDate(
        inputFormat: String = "yyyy-MM-dd",
        outputFormat: String,
        inputDate: String,
        locale: Locale = Locale("EN")
    ): String {
        val inputFormat = inputFormat
        var outputFormat = outputFormat

        if (outputFormat == "") {
            outputFormat = "EEEE d 'de' MMMM 'del' yyyy" // if inputFormat = "", set a default output format.
        }
        var parsed: Date? = null
        var outputDate = ""

        val dfInput = SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, locale)
        val dfOutput = SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat, locale)

        try {
            parsed = dfInput.parse(inputDate)
            outputDate = dfOutput.format(parsed)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("formattedDateFromString", "Exception in formate Date From string(): " + e.message)
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return outputDate

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function for any conversion of date,it will work :)

**In Java**

```
/**
 * Changes date format from one format to another format.
 *
 * @param fromFormat format of received date string.
 * @param toFormat   format of returned(needed) date string.
 * @param date       date whose format is to be changed in string.
 * @return date string formatted into toFormat
 */
public static String changeDateFormat(String fromFormat, String toFormat, String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat toDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);

    try {
        return toDateFormat.format(dateFormat.parse(date));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "NA";
    }
}
```

**In Kotlin**

```
fun changeDateFormat(fromFormat: String, toFormat: String, date: String): String {
        val toDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(toFormat)
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat)
        return try {
            toDateFormat.format(dateFormat.parse(date))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            "NA"
        }

    }
```

In Code

```
AppLogs.e(
        "DATE",
        Utility.changeDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd", "Sun Jun 23 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2019")
    )
```