# Formatting Joda-Time DateTime to String

Tags: java, android, time, jodatime, android-jodatime

I'm stuck with converting DateTime format to String, I just can't get any idea how to get only Hours Minutes and Seconds from this type correctly. When I tried my way I get something like `2020-01-17T20:19:00`. But I need to get just `20:19:00`.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime; 

public DateTime orderDateFrom;
Log.d(TAG, orderDateFrom.toString());
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277747/android-simpledateformat-how-to-use-it

Comment: which kind of DateTime? (what do you *import*)?

Comment: I got exact DateTime type variable, it's coming from server, and I interested is there a way to get exact Time units without converting to side types like Khodor adviced

Comment: Can you provide more code and also the exact import?

Comment: @KishanMaurya, did you know there is no "getDate" function is DateTime?

Comment: @JavierHeisecke, sure, that is import -> import org.joda.time.DateTime;
And about more code I'm afraid I just got Dto from server and trying to conver field orderDateFrom of DateTime type from it

Comment: If you're working with JodaTime, there seem to be methods for hours, minutes and seconds: [https://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#Querying_DateTimes](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#Querying_DateTimes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using Joda-Time, I recommend you choose between two options:

1. Stick with Joda-Time for now.
2. Upgrade to java.time, the modern Java date and time API and the successor of Joda-Time.

The option I certainly whole-heartedly discourage is going back to `Date` and `SimpleDateFOrmat` from Java 1.0 and 1.1. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome.

### Stick with Joda-Time

If you want the time from your `DateTime` formatted into a `String`, for example for output to the user:

```
    DateTime orderDateFrom = new DateTime(2020, 1, 17, 20, 19, 0, DateTimeZone.forID("Mexico/BajaSur"));

    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedTime = orderDateFrom.toString(timeFormatter);
    System.out.println("Order time: " + formattedTime);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> Order time: 20:19:00

If you want the time of day as an object that you can use for further procesing:

```
    LocalTime orderTime = orderDateFrom.toLocalTime();
    System.out.println("Order time: " + orderTime);
```

> Order time: 20:19:00.000

We notice that this time three decimals on the second of minute are also printed since the no-arg `toString` method does that. You can format the `LocalTime` using the same formatter as above to obtain the same string if you like.

### A note on java.time on Android

If programming for Android API level 26 and/or above, java.time comes built-in. If you need to take lower API levels into account, java.time comes as an external dependency just like Joda-Time: the ThreeTenABP. That’s ThreeTen for JSR-310, where java.time was first described, and ABP for Android Backport. See the links at the bottom.

The code will be similar, not identical to the code using Joda-Time above.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7.
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
This will get time as 23:10:04 format

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;


        public DateTime orderDateFrom;

        Date d = orderDateFrom.toDate();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(d);
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exatly what I want!

Comment: Happy I could help :)

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not when the questioner is already using the more modern and more programmer-friendly Joda-Time. Today we even have even better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome SimpleDateFormat class. At least not when the questioner is already using the more modern and more programmer-friendly Joda-Time. Today we even have even better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way to do this but you could just get the substring.

```
String orderDateStr = orderDateFrom.toString();
orderDateStr.substring(orderDateStr.lastIndexOf("T")+1);
```

Comment: Oh, no, thank you, but that is deffinitly not what I want to do) I know how to substring