# Correct way to parse Date in Kotlin Android (Minimum Android Version 21). My parse is not working

Tags: java, android, date, kotlin, parsing

I want to parse this date in this format 2021-11-03T14:09:31.135Z (`message.created_at`)

My code is this:

```
val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS")
var convertedDate = Date()
try {
    convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(message.created_at)
} catch (e: ParseException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

It is failing to parse

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` are part of the legacy Java time APIs. `java.time` is the modern replacement and is part of Java 8. In Android it's only available in [API level 26 and up](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary), **but** it can be used almost entirely in earlier versions using [API desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Please consider switching to `java.time`. It's just plain better.

Comment: Yes, other people are also suggesting this. Will have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the format not entirely what the string looks like:

- You have a space instead of the `T` literal between the date and the time
- You have no offset notation at the end
- You are using `hh`, which is 12-hour format. Use `HH` instead.

This format should do it:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX
```

---

However, note that `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are obsolete and [troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api). Use `java.time` instead. If your Android API level appears to be too low, you could use [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Comment: Yes, will consider the suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `SimpleDateFormat` it's long [outdated and troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).
Use `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the date.

```
 fun parseDate() {
        var formatter: DateTimeFormatter? = null
        val date = "2021-11-03T14:09:31.135Z" // your date string
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX") // formatter
            val dateTime: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, parser) // date object
            val formatter2: DateTimeFormatter =
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMM d : HH:mm") // if you want to convert it any other format
            Log.e("Date", "" + dateTime.format(formatter2))
        }
    }
```

**Output:** Wednesday, Nov 3 : 14:09

To use this below android 8 , use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)

Comment: Problem is solved by previous answers. Thanks for help.

Comment: SuryakantBharti , that's great , but I will still suggest you migrate to modern java api - referring to @deHarr answer or mine, You can read about [reason by new date time api were formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277747/android-simpledateformat-how-to-use-it) , answer by Arwind Kumar , or a google search might give you more reasons

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will have a look into it.

Comment: This is definitely using the most modern API. I just think the approach to treat `Z` as a literal by escaping it via single quotes although it means *UTC* is quite a hack. The `String` clearly denotes a date and time plus offset, which is reflected by the class `OffsetDateTime` and only partially by `LocalDateTime` which doesn't hold information about a zone. If one really needs a `LocalDateTime` one could always call `toLocalDateTime()` from an instance of `OffsetDateTime`.

Answer (score 4):

try it

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS")
    var convertedDate = Date()
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse("2021-11-03T14:09:31.135Z")
        println(convertedDate)
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your minimum API level is 21, you can use [API Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support), find some nice explanations about it [here](https://blog.mindorks.com/desugaring-in-android).

As soon as you have enabled API Desugaring, you can directly parse your ISO `String` to an `OffsetDateTime`:

```kotlin
val convertedDate = OffsetDateTime.parse(message.created_at)
```

Comment: Problem is solved by previous answers. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You have just missed "T" in the date format string. use this solution for your date parsing.

```
fun formatDate(inputDate: String) {
    var convertedDate = Date()
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.getDefault())
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(inputDate)
        print("Parsed date $convertedDate")
    } catch (ignored: ParseException) {
    }

    //if you wish to change the parsed date into another formatted date
    val dfOutput = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
    val str :String = dfOutput.format(convertedDate)
    print("Formatted date $str")
}
```

Just pass your "message.created_at" as an input parameter. For more date time formats check out this official documentation of Android Developers site.
 [SimpleDateFormat | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) you will get all the possible date formats here.

Cheers..!