# How to parse date "2022-07-18T08:24:18Z" in android

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime-parsing

I have tried these format but none worked.

1. yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
2. yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
3. yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ
4. yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss

Also tried "ZonedDateTime", but it is not available below Android O.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to parse Date in Kotlin Android (Minimum Android Version 21). My parse is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69987822/correct-way-to-parse-date-in-kotlin-android-minimum-android-version-21-my-par)

Comment: @Ivo tried this too. But not working. In my case there is no "milisec"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We love to help with code that is not working, only we need a [mre], please? We also need to know what you mean by *none worked*, please. Please paste any wrong result and/or any error message verbatim into the question.

Comment: Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597083/illegal-pattern-character-t-when-parsing-a-date-string-to-java-util-date) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941357/iso-8601-string-to-date-time-object-in-android), For pattern 2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168647/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz-simple). Don’t worry about not having millis, just adapt any pattern to not have. For Android below O [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191152/convert-string-date-to-date-in-android-java-kotlin-without-having-to-deal-with)

Answer (score 2):

If your minSDK is 25 or lower you have to use [Java 8+ API desugaring support](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)  to be able to use the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package from Java 8.

With that enabled you can simply use e.g.

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("2022-07-18T08:24:18Z")
ZonedDateTime.parse("2022-07-18T08:24:18Z")
```

(you can find many resources about the differences of these date formats).

Comment: Or depending on what you need ot for: `Instant.parse("2022-07-18T08:24:18Z")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
fun parseDate(
        inputDateString: String?,
        inputDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat,
        outputDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat
    ): String? {
        var date: Date? = null
        var outputDateString: String? = null
        try {
            date = inputDateFormat.parse(inputDateString)
            outputDateString = outputDateFormat.format(date)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return outputDateString
    }
```

- inputString will be your Date, ex:"2022-07-18T08:24:18Z"
- inputDateFormat : SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",
  Locale.US)
- outputDateFormat : in whichever format you want to show the date

I hope you get your answer from this

Comment: Already mentioned in question. This format is not working

Comment: I tried and tested it. Use my parseDate method with it.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android look into [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

Comment: I believe it will give 08:24:18 in my own time zone where 08:24:18 UTC was intended, so not correct (have not tested).